# Discrete vs. continuous Fourier transform for a continuous time process

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, fourier-transform, matlab, fast-fourier-transform

my objective is to prove why we **can't** use fft (which uses DFT) to calculate the PSD on a continuous time process.

The teacher instractures word by word are:

go to Matlab and read help on fft(), copy the DTF formula it is implementing and compare to the formula that should be implemented in our case, since we have a continuous time process and not a discrete time process! Then complete the computation of PSD for continuous time, as you said: from X(f) and X*(f). Then conclude whether it is possible to use fft() function and obtain the same result as you developed for continuous time. If yes, explain how.

my calculation of the PSD is
$$S_X(f)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi f\tau j}R_X(\tau) d\tau = \frac{\sigma^2}{2\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi f\tau j}e^{-\alpha |\tau |}d\tau=\frac{\sigma ^2}{4\pi ^2f^2+\alpha ^2}$$

Matlab's DTF:
$$\sum_{j=1}^nX(j)W_n^{(j-1)(k-1)}$$ Where $$W_n=e^{\frac{-2\pi i}{n}}$$

The process is $$X'(t)+\alpha X(t) = Z(t), t \ge 0,  X(0) = 0  $$
where Z is zero mean white Gaussian noise.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Your instructor probably wants you to change the sum to a Riemann-Stieltjes integral and extend the domain of the $W_n$ functions to continuous time...

Comment: The digital Fourier transform (DFT) is a unitary operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. FFT is just an implementation of the DFT. In other words, the DFT computes the coefficients of a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the Fourier basis. The discrete Fourier transform computes the Schauder basis coefficients for continuous compactly supported functions. The continuous time Fourier transform extends this idea to square integrable functions over $\mathbb{R}$. This isn't a basis representation (the existence of a basis for square integrable functions is guaranteed by Zorn's lemma if we accept axiom of choice.)